# How do I Reach Windows 10's Settings' Taskbar's Choose Which Icons Appear in the Taskbar Programmatically?

Tags: windows-10

I'm looking for a way to directly get to the Windows 10 > Settings > Taskbar > Selection Which Icons Appear on the Task bar.

- The closest I got was ms-settings:taskbar
- I also tried the ancient: explorer shell:::{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9} // this works on some Win 10 machines while not on others.
- I also considered creating a batch via cmd and was hoping that I can programmatically send a mouse-click on the URI, but that does not work without some major shell scripting.
- Yes I could simply use Autohotkey to launch step 1 and then send a mouse-click to the URI, but I was hoping there was a native brew.

This is as far as I got, any ideas?

Comment: Reach it via what means? Is this for a shortcut you'll have on your computer, a link in a document?

Comment: Instead of trying to do something that isn’t possible, is there a reason, you are not simply modifying the associated registry key?

Comment: @music2myear, s shortcut on my desktop.

Comment: @Ramhound, if you have a solution, please add it to this post as one.